# UIButtons initially non-functional when positioned on the right-hand side of a view

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

All:

I am working on an app in which I have multiple `UIButtons` and `UITextFields` on the top and right hand side of a `UIView`.  The `UIViewController` is embedded in a tab bar controller, and I'm using iOS 7.

When the view first appears, the `UIButtons` and `UITextFields` on the right are unresponsive -- they are enabled (according to `.isEnabled`), but the buttons don't flash, and the keyboard doesn't appear when I tap on the `UITextField`.  If I switch to another tab and then back, they work.

The controls at the top work as expected.

However, if I drag the right hand side controls more towards the center of the app, they work first time.  There's like a 100 pixel "dead zone" that only goes away when I switch tabs.

Update:  If I bypass the tab bar controller completely, and make the view controller associated with the above the initial view controller, then the controls work as they should.

What is going on??

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Check the frames of all the views that enclose the buttons. If the button and the text field sit outside the view of any enclosing frames then you may not be able to interact with them. Use `[[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` to see how things are laid out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Xcode doesn't seem to know about recursiveDescription ("no known instance method for selector 'recursiveDescription'"), and it also mutters about "no known class method for selector 'keyWindow'".  I ended up just recreating a tabbed app, and then dragged in all my files, copied-and-pasted into Storyboard, and now things work as they should.

Comment: `-recursiveDescription` is an undocumented method of UIView which can be used during debugging: see [Technical Note TN2239 iOS Debugging Magic / UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION34).